# How to produce a "Callable function"

Tags: python, numpy, callable

I am currently writing a python definition called f_from_data which uses interpolation find point on a line so far I have written this:

```
def f_from_data(xs, ys, x):
    xfine = np.linspace(min(xs), max(xs), 10000)
    y0 = inter.interp1d(xs, ys, kind = 'linear')
    ans = (y0(xfine))[numpy.searchsorted(xfine, x)]
    ans =  round(ans,2)
    return ans
```

This is giving me what I want to I need to make it so I can enter:

```
f = f_from_data([3, 4, 6], [0, 1, 2])
print f(3)
>>>0.0
```

How do I go about doing this? I've looked around but can't seem to find anything as I think its really trivial but I'm just missing somthing.

Comment: FYI, this process is called [partial function application](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application).

Answer (score 13):

Using `functools.partial`:

```
from functools import partial

f = partial(f_from_data, [3, 4, 6], [0, 1, 2])
```

`partial` will create a callable object with the first 2 arguments already set.

Answer (score 3):

[interpolate.interp1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d) returns a callable:

```
import scipy.interpolate as interpolate

f_from_data = interpolate.interp1d
f = f_from_data([3, 4, 6], [0, 1, 2])
print(f(3))
```

yields

```
0.0
```

Since `f_from_data` can be assigned to `interpolate.interp1d`, you may not  need `f_from_data` at all. Now, it is true that this does not chop the x-range into 10000 grid points, and use searchsorted to snap the x value to a nearby grid point, but in general you wouldn't want to do that anyway since `interp1d` gives you a better linear interpolation without it.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this?

```
def f_from_data(xs, ys):
    def interpolate(x):
       xfine = np.linspace(min(xs), max(xs), 10000)
       y0 = inter.interp1d(xs, ys, kind = 'linear')
       ans = (y0(xfine))[numpy.searchsorted(xfine, x)]
       ans =  round(ans,2)
       return ans
    return interpolate
```

Warning - I don't know matplotlib well enough to say whether the code is correct.

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is simple, here it is a simple solution

```
>>> f = lambda x: f_from_data([3, 4, 6], [0, 1, 2], x)
>>> print f(3)
0.0
>>>
```

If you dislike `lambda`

```
>>> def f(x): return f_from_data([3, 4, 6], [0, 1, 2], x)
```

In both cases you must be sure that `f_from_data` is in scope when you define the auxiliary function.

Answer (score 1):

The more general approach would be to create a class with a `__call__` method, so something like this:

```
class f_from_data(object):
    def __init__(self, xs, ys):
        self.xfine = np.linspace(min(xs), max(xs), 10000)
        self.y0 = inter.interp1d(xs, ys, kind = 'linear')
    def __call__(self, x):
        ans = (self.y0(self.xfine))[numpy.searchsorted(self.xfine, x)]
        return round(ans, 2)
```

Comment: While this may be common in other contexts, it'd be *extremely* unusual in numpy code.

Comment: What makes it unusual in numpy code? It is the way, e.g. `scipy.interpolate` makes all its function-returning 1D interpolators work, see [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/interpolate/polyint.py#L21), how `numpy.poly1d` handles polynomial-evaluating functions, see [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/3ef77eea0d9c2cd76bc9b89b04a32f1322f842d5/numpy/lib/polynomial.py#L939), or `numpy.vectorize` makes vectorized functions, see [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/3ef77eea0d9c2cd76bc9b89b04a32f1322f842d5/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L1577).